# Super+V (Show the notification list) not working

Tags: 20.04, gnome, shortcuts

As can be seen in the picture:

[image]

I have <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> mapped to the command that is mapped to by default, yet the notification panel is never opened when I use it. Maybe Dash to Panel is conflicting with it? I have no idea. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify: you show a picture with Ctrl+V then refer in your question to Super+M? By default, both Super+M and Super+V open the notification list.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, it was Super+V. Neither Super+V nor Super+M open the notification list, though.